# How to get Core Data Object with Object itself as ID?

Tags: ios, swift

i read out all my Core Data Objects using:

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "QuestionsSelectOption")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "questions = %@", currentQuestion!)
selectOptions = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [QuestionsSelectOption]
```

And now i can use my Objects with

```
let myTestObject = selectOptions(index) as QuestionsSelectOption
```

But how do i update a Core Data Object without any Identifier? How can i make a NSPredicate with my Object itself as my ID?

Or what is the best way to update (in this case) "myTestObject" in Swift? I could use the Index, but i dont think that is a good way.

Edit: Now i use:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", myTestObject)
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as Array

    if(results.count == 1) {

        let currentQuestionSelectOption = results[0] as QuestionsSelectOption

        currentQuestionSelectOption.selected = selected

        context.save(nil)
    }
```

It works - But is there not an easier/better solution?

Comment: Just update all properties of `myTestObject` then save it via managedObjectContext's save method.

Comment: Can u specify the save method? Now i use it like in my edit (that works fine, but i dont know if that is a good solution)

Comment: `managedObjectContext.save(error: NSErrorPointer!)`

Comment: Just modify the `selected` property of `myTestObject` call context.save then that's it. Because `results[0]` if any is actually `myTestObject`.

Comment: Oh that is fine - it works perfect! Thank you so much (provide it as answer at i will set it as accepted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify the `selected` property of `myTestObject` call `context.save()` then that's it. Because `results[0]` if any is actually `myTestObject`.